# Python Turtle Collision Help and Updating Score/Lives

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am working on a scrolling game that uses multiple turtles. The player turtle moves on the Y-Axis on key commands. While the Harm and Benefits move across the X-Axis then looping around and changing Y-Axis position. I have tried defining a function called `colliding()` that can test if the  player and benefit turtles collide. Can someone help with the collision function? And I also have a question on how, after detecting collision, to change the value of the player score? I think I have figured this out: I used `player['lives']+=1`. But this doesn't change because -- is something wrong with my collision function or loop?

```
import turtle
import random
import math

#The list of the turtles being used
t = turtle.Turtle()
Harm1 = turtle.Turtle()       
Harm2 = turtle.Turtle()
Ben = turtle.Turtle()
player1 = turtle.Turtle()

#Screen Specifications
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(500,500)
screen.bgcolor('darkgray')
Harm1.tracer(0)
Harm2.tracer(0)
Ben.tracer(0)
player1.tracer(0)


#Character dictionary
player ={"type":'Player',"x" : -200,"y" : 0,"size" : 20,"speed" : 10,
"color" : "green","Lives":3,"Score":0}

harm = {"type":'Harm',"x" : -200,"y" : 0,"size" : 30,"speed" : 6,
"color" : "red",}

benefit = {"type":'Benefit',"x" : -200,"y" : 0,"size" : 15,"speed":6,
"color" : "yellow",}

#These can change when collision happens
lives = player['Lives']
score = player['Score']

#These are the keys that let the player move up/down
def move_up():
  player['y']+=player['speed']
  return
def move_down():
  player['y']-= player['speed']

#Player gets info from dictionary
def draw_player():
  player1.clear()
  player1.penup()
  player1.goto(player["x"], player["y"])  
  player1.pendown()
  player1.color(player["color"])
  player1.begin_fill()
  player1.circle(player["size"])
  player1.end_fill()
  #if player1(player['y']) > 250 or player1(player['y']) < -250:
     #player1.sety(player['y'])
  player1.update()
  player1.hideturtle()
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(move_up, 'up')
screen.onkey(move_down, 'down')

def draw_harms():
  Harm1.clear()
  Harm1.color(harm['color'])
  Harm1.begin_fill()
  Harm1.circle(harm['size'])
  Harm1.end_fill()
  Harm1.update()
  Harm1.setx(Harm1.xcor()-(harm['speed']))
  if (Harm1.xcor() < -260 ): #This part of the code makes the object comeback.
     Harm1.setx(260)
     Harm1.sety(random.randint(-160,160)) #This makes the object change Y cor
  Harm1.hideturtle()
  Harm2.clear()
  Harm2.color(harm['color'])
  Harm2.begin_fill()
  Harm2.circle(harm['size'])
  Harm2.end_fill()
  Harm2.update()
  Harm2.setx(Harm2.xcor()-(harm['speed']))
  if (Harm2.xcor() < -260 ): #This part of the code makes the object comeback.
     Harm2.setx(220)
     Harm2.sety(random.randint(-160,160)) #This makes the object change Y cor
  Harm2.hideturtle()

def draw_benefit():
  Ben.clear()
  Ben.color(benefit['color'])
  Ben.begin_fill()
  Ben.circle(benefit['size'])
  Ben.end_fill()
  Ben.update()
  Ben.setx(Ben.xcor()-(benefit['speed']))
  if (Ben.xcor() < -260 ): #This part of the code makes the object comeback.
     Ben.setx(220)
     Ben.sety(random.randint(-160,160)) #This makes the object change Y cor
  Ben.hideturtle()   


#This Keeps the score and Lives
def draw_title_name(): #This writes the title on the screen
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-210,-200)
  t.pendown()
  t.write(("Score:", score),font=("Arial", 18, "normal"))
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-210,-223)
  t.pendown()
  t.write(('Lives:',lives),font=('Arial',18,'normal'))
  t.hideturtle()
  return


def colliding(player,benefit):
  collision_detected = False;
  var_dx = player['x'] - benefit['x']
  var_dy = player['y'] - benefit['y']
  distance = math.sqrt(var_dx * var_dx + var_dy * var_dy)
  if (distance < player['radius']+ benefit['radius']):
    collision_detected = True;
  return collision_detected



while lives > 0: #ANIMATION LOOP
  draw_player()
  draw_harms()
  draw_benefit()
  draw_title_name()
  if colliding == True:
    player['lives'] += 1 This changes the lives in the player Dict






  if lives == 0:
    clearscreen
    #Finish with a gameover screen!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a disaster, there are any number of bits of logic in it that will keep it from running.  To address your question, turtle has it's own `distance()` method to measure the distance between turtles or turtles and positions.  Using that, your `colliding()` method could be as simple as:

```
def colliding(player, benefit):
    return player.distance(benefit) < player_dict['size'] + benefit_dict['size']
```

if you were to actually call your `colliding()` method, which you don't, as @Hoog points out.  Other showstoppers in this code:

```
if (distance < player['radius']+ benefit['radius']):
```

The `radius` properties are never defined.

```
var_dx = player['x'] - benefit['x']
```

Although player's x position is updated in the dictionary, benefit's isn't, so this will never work.

```
player['lives'] += 1 This changes the lives in the player Dict
```

Missing comment character.

```
clearscreen
```

What is this?  Probably should be `screen.clearscreen()`.

```
collision_detected = False;
...
collision_detected = True;
```

semicolons in Python are usually a sign that things aren't going well.

```
Harm1 = turtle.Turtle()       
Harm2 = turtle.Turtle()
Ben = turtle.Turtle()
player1 = turtle.Turtle()
...
Harm1.tracer(0)
Harm2.tracer(0)
Ben.tracer(0)
player1.tracer(0)
```

Turtle instances don't respond to the `tracer()` method.  Screen instances do.

```
player1.update()
Harm1.update()
Harm2.update()
Ben.update()
```

Ditto for `update()`.  And so forth.

Below is my rework of your code to make it basically run:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

FONT = ('Arial', 18, 'normal')
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

# Character dictionaries
player_dict = {'type': 'Player', 'x': -200, 'y': 0, 'radius': 20, 'speed':10, 'color': 'green', 'lives': 3, 'score': 0}

harm_dict = {'type': 'Harm', 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'radius' : 30, 'speed': 6, 'color': 'red'}

benefit_dict = {'type': 'Benefit', 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'radius': 15, 'speed': 6, 'color': 'yellow'}

# These are the keys that let the player move up/down
def move_up():
    player_dict['y'] += player_dict['speed']

def move_down():
    player_dict['y'] -= player_dict['speed']

# Player gets info from dictionary
def draw_player():
    player1.sety(player_dict['y'])

def draw_harms():
    harm1.forward(harm_dict['speed'])

    if harm1.xcor() < -250 - harm_dict['radius']:  # This part of the code makes the object come back.
        harm1.hideturtle()
        harm1.setx(250 + harm_dict['radius'])
        harm1.sety(randint(-160, 160))  # This makes the object change Y coordinate
        harm1.showturtle()

    harm2.forward(harm_dict['speed'])

    if harm2.xcor() < -250 - harm_dict['radius']:  # This part of the code makes the object comeback.
        harm2.hideturtle()
        harm2.setx(250 + harm_dict['radius'])
        harm2.sety(randint(-160, 160))  # This makes the object change Y coordinate
        harm2.showturtle()

def draw_benefit():
    ben.forward(benefit_dict['speed'])

    if ben.xcor() < -250 - benefit_dict['radius']:  # This part of the code makes the object comeback.
        ben.hideturtle()
        ben.setx(250 + benefit_dict['radius'])
        ben.sety(randint(-160, 160))  # This makes the object change Y coordinate
        ben.showturtle()

# This Keeps the score and Lives
def draw_lives():
    lives.undo()
    lives.write("Lives: {}".format(player_dict['lives']), font=FONT)

def draw_score():
    score.undo()
    score.write("Score: {}".format(player_dict['score']), font=FONT)

def colliding(player, benefit):
    return player.distance(benefit) < player_dict['radius'] + benefit_dict['radius']

# Screen Specifications
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.bgcolor('darkgray')

# The list of the turtles being used
t = Turtle(visible=False)
t.penup()

harm1 = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
harm1.color(harm_dict['color'])
harm1.shapesize(harm_dict['radius'] * 2 / CURSOR_SIZE)
harm1.penup()
harm1.setx(250 + harm_dict['radius'])
harm1.sety(randint(-160, 160))
harm1.setheading(180)
harm1.showturtle()

harm2 = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
harm2.color(harm_dict['color'])
harm2.shapesize(harm_dict['radius'] * 2 / CURSOR_SIZE)
harm2.penup()
harm2.setx(250 + harm_dict['radius'])
harm2.sety(randint(-160, 160))
harm2.setheading(180)
harm2.showturtle()

ben = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
ben.color(benefit_dict['color'])
ben.shapesize(benefit_dict['radius'] * 2 / CURSOR_SIZE)
ben.penup()
ben.setx(250 + benefit_dict['radius'])
ben.sety(randint(-160, 160))
ben.setheading(180)
ben.showturtle()

player1 = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
player1.color(player_dict['color'])
player1.shapesize(player_dict['radius'] * 2 / CURSOR_SIZE)
player1.penup()
player1.goto(player_dict['x'], player_dict['y'])
player1.showturtle()

score = Turtle(visible=False)
score.penup()
score.goto(-210, -200)
score.write("Score: {}".format(player_dict['score']), font=FONT)

lives = Turtle(visible=False)
lives.penup()
lives.goto(-210, -223)
lives.write("Lives: {}".format(player_dict['lives']), font=FONT)

screen.onkey(move_up, 'Up')
screen.onkey(move_down, 'Down')
screen.listen()

def move():
    draw_player()
    draw_harms()
    draw_benefit()
    # draw_score()

    if colliding(player1, ben):
        player_dict['lives'] += 1  # This increases the lives in the player dictionary
        ben.hideturtle()
        ben.setx(250 + benefit_dict['radius'])
        ben.sety(randint(-160, 160))
        ben.showturtle()
        draw_lives()

    if colliding(player1, harm1):
        player_dict['lives'] -= 1  # This decreases the lives in the player dictionary
        harm1.hideturtle()
        harm1.setx(250 + harm_dict['radius'])
        harm1.sety(randint(-160, 160))
        harm1.showturtle()
        draw_lives()

    if colliding(player1, harm2):
        player_dict['lives'] -= 1
        harm2.hideturtle()
        harm2.setx(250 + harm_dict['radius'])
        harm2.sety(randint(-160, 160))
        harm2.showturtle()
        draw_lives()

    if player_dict['lives'] == 0:
        screen.clearscreen()
        # Finish with a gameover screen!
        return

    if player_dict['lives'] > 0:
        screen.ontimer(move, 75)

move()
screen.mainloop()
```

It still needs a lot of work, however.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame has a built in collision detection algorithm `rect.colliderect()` which might help you out.

For your code the issue seems to be this line `if colliding == True:` you never set the variable colliding, perhaps you meant to call the function with something like: `if colliding(Player1,Ben1) == True:`

Comment: For your suggestion of "if colliding(Player1,Ben1)" were you refrencing the turtle itself or the player dictionary? @Hoog

Comment: This should reference individual `Turtle` object.  Whichever object has the necessary  `['x']` and `['y']` associated with where the player is and where the benefit is should be what you're looking for.

Comment: So I put in the correct parameters as you suggested but I get a KeyError: radius on line 118. @Hoog

Comment: It doesn't look like you set `player['radius'] anywhere.  Should that be size instead?

Comment: I caught that and i fixed it to player['radius']. But now i run into the problem that lives changes on its own even without collision. Take a look https://repl.it/@ioliva5/Project-20      @Hoog

Comment: Your colliding function is returning True all of the time.  I would suggest a couple of things to help figure out why:  First I would add a "Frame Counter" that will keep track of how many times you've been through the while loop by adding one each time.   Second is you can use this frame counter to only do things every 10,50,100 frames.  This should let you actually read what is printed instead of it writing over and over.  With this you can test all the variables going into the colliding function and maybe find one that is causing your error.